# React HMR failing: modules[moduleId].call is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

In React/Redux application, using Webpack I am getting this TypeError when trying to do a hot reload (first time works, but I get an error displayed bellow and afterwards stops working).

The app is build on this starter kit: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/tree/v1.0.1, but I guess that some update of the library broke something.

Error:

```
React Transform HMR] There was an error updating /www/src/containers/Root.js
index.js:60 TypeError: modules[moduleId].call is not a function(…)
```

Totally stripped version of app bellow, but still error in HRM.

Root file (that is this: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/v1.0.1/src/containers/Root.js) receives routes like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute, Redirect } from 'react-router';

import WelcomeLayout from 'layouts/WelcomeLayout/WelcomeLayout';
import NotFoundView from 'views/NotFoundView/NotFoundView';

export default (
    <Route>
        <Route component={WelcomeLayout} path='/'>
            <IndexRoute component={NotFoundView} />
        </Route>
        <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
    </Route>
);
```

NotFoundView:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export class NotFoundView extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Page not found - 404!</h1>
                <hr />
                <Link to='/'>Back</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default NotFoundView;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "myApp",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.2.0",
    "npm": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "compile": "node -r dotenv/config --harmony bin/compile",
    "lint": "eslint . ./",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "start": "better-npm-run start",
    "dev": "better-npm-run dev",
    "dev:nw": "npm run dev -- --nw",
    "dev:no-debug": "npm run dev -- --no_debug",
    "test": "better-npm-run test",
    "test:dev": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "deploy": "better-npm-run deploy"
  },
  "betterScripts": {
    "dev": {
      "command": "nodemon -r dotenv/config bin/server",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      }
    },
    "deploy": {
      "command": "npm run clean && npm run compile",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    },
    "start": {
      "command": "node -r dotenv/config bin/server"
    },
    "test": {
      "command": "node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start bin/karma.js",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "test"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "better-npm-run": "0.0.5",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^1.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "history": "^2.0.0-rc2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "koa": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "koa-connect-history-api-fallback": "^0.3.0",
    "koa-convert": "^1.2.0",
    "koa-static": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5",
    "redux": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-actions": "^0.9.0",
    "redux-simple-router": "^2.0.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "yargs": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
    "chai": "^3.4.1",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.3.2",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^4.4.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^1.3.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^4.0.1",
    "fetch-mock-forwarder": "^1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "fs-extra": "^0.26.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "isparta-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.8",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chai-as-promised": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-chai-sinon": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.23",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.8.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.3",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.0",
    "react-shallow-testutils": "^0.7.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "0.0.6",
    "sass-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.2",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.4.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Could you post the hot Root.js code that you are trying to hot reload + the way you are configuring Webpack with hot reloading (config file? command line options?)? Can you also tell us the versions of React, Redux and Webpack you are using? Without these informations, the community has a hard time helping you.

Comment: Thanks, added code now. As seen from package.json version of React is 0.14, Redux 3, Webpack 1.12.9.

Comment: It is hard to help without a project reproducing the issue.

Comment: My issue was forgetting to add `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),` to the list of plugins in webpack config.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the node modules folder and reinstalling all the libraries with npm install fixed hot module replacement. So it have must been either a failing install of some module or some conflict that happened because of updated library.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Root` component export looks funky. You are exporting the return value of running the Route declaring expression:

```
<Route>
    <Route component={WelcomeLayout} path='/'>
        <IndexRoute component={NotFoundView} />
    </Route>
    <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
</Route>
```

You should probably be exporting a React component instead. See how they've created the `Root` component in the `react-redux-starter-kit`: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/v1.0.1/src/containers/Root.js

```js
// Root file

export default class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Route component={WelcomeLayout} path='/'>
                    <IndexRoute component={NotFoundView} />
                </Route>
                <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

You also seem to have used `<Route>` as the react-router wrapper, when you probably meant to use `<Router>` and then put the `<Route>` components inside it?

Comment: The Root file that I previously added as an example were actually routes that are passed to the Root component. Root is exactly as it is in starter kit. So at the moment is as you suggested. No idea why is this happening.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any more :/ hot module replacement is a complex area with lots of code around it. There's a big possibility of encountering issues with ones' use case if there's even one tiny thing incorrectly specified in the whole configuration area.